# How Can I set the background of a browser window blend with the desktop background?

Tags: node-webkit, blend

I'm trying to build an app with nwjs, and I want it to have the look and feel of a desktop app. Desktop apps on OSX (Specifically the ones on the upper menu) have their background blend with the desktop background.

Does anyone know how can I do this in a browser, or simply in nwjs (Node-Webkit)?

Thanks,
Adir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was going the wrong way. The blend mode is available for menus only.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of window transparency? If so this is possible in newish versions of NWJS. (node-webkit >= v0.11.2)

https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Transparency